# Author message can be interpreted as integer in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I wanted to create a bot that can remind me for an event that I set up. First, I'll give **'create**  command and it will ask me to input the name for the event. Then, the bot will ask about the time I want to be reminded. Then I will put a number ex; 2. But it won't work and says `TypeError: 'Message' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`. This is my code.

```
import os
from discord import client
from discord.ext.commands.errors import NoPrivateMessage

from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN='my token here'

client=commands.Bot(command_prefix="\'",description='Hey, I\'m MyBot')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))


@client.command()
async def create(ctx):
    if ctx.author==client.user:
        return

    await ctx.channel.send(f'What is the name for your event: ')

    @client.event
    async def on_message(name):
        if name.author==client.user:
            return

        await name.channel.send(f'When you want to be reminded:')
        
        @client.event
        async def on_message(time:int):
        
            if time.author!=client.user:
                x=0
                for x in range(time):
                    await time.channel.send(x)
                    #pass

                else :
                    event_name=str(time.content)         
                    await time.channel.send(event_name)


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    await client.process_commands(message)
    username=str(message.author).split('#')[0]
    user_message=str(message.content)
    channel=(str(message.channel.name))
    print(f'{username}:{user_message} ({channel})')   

    if message.author==client.user:
        return

client.run(TOKEN)
```

I'm trying to debugging by using another code that serve the same function which is

```
    for x in range(a):
        print(x)

#print(a)

test(10)
```

And it worked. So I don't really know for sure what is wrong in my code. Hope somebody can help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`on_message` always takes `message` as a parameter. So It will cause error while type casting it to int as message is a object and not a string.

You can use this answer insted

```py
import asyncio

@client.command()
@commands.guild_only()
async def create(ctx):
    msg = await ctx.send('When you want me to remind?')
    message = await bot.wait_for('message',check=lambda m: m.author==ctx.author and m.channel=ctx.channel,timeout=60)
    # Considering message sent was an int
    try:
        time_to_use = int(message.content)
        # Then you can do your rest of the code.
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await ctx.send("You failed to answer in time")
```

Comment: sorry but i dont really understand how and where to use those code. Im just a beginner

Comment: `bot.wait_for` waits for a event (event can be anything like message or reaction) the first argument it takes is the event name as string, second argument it takes the filter that you want (like a message which is not yours is also a message event) and the last argument is the time it will wait until it stops.

Comment: remember to add try except to except aasyncio.TimeoutError when the time of listening ends.  
And yes I forgot that wile answering and I have edited it now